# Netbook for Developer

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, netbook

HI,

I need a move compact laptop for travel, I am looking into getting a 10" netbook which will beable to let me run a decent LAMP environment.

I was looking into HP they seem to have the fastest ATOM processor and capable of 2GB of RAM.  Does anyone have any advice for me ?

Cheers.

Comment: If the 10" isn't a firm size but you just want a lightweight, portable laptop that's powerful, look into the Lenovo ThinkPad X201.  These things weigh less than a lot of 10" netbooks.

Comment: According to [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), questions related to shopping recommendations are outside of this site's scope. If you want to have a site where they will be on-topic, consider supporting [Technology Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20084/technology-recommendations?referrer=gzI5eQiwHlZfuQ5vY_kYhA2)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it has a usable keyboard! (Or take a full-sized USB one with you.)
I've tried to use my EeePC for development and, frankly, it's a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, it's not the LAMP setup you're going to need the specs for. Consider that you can happily run LAMP on a machine with 128M or less RAM. Just about anything that'll run Linux is fine for a LAMP development machine, so that has little bearing on your choice.

If you're not bothered about a graphical desktop environment, you could probably buy the cheapest netbook you can find and do perfectly fine developing with lynx and {insert cli editor of choice}.

Answer (score 0):

I you want a full-powered netbook sized laptop, consider the [ThinkPad X201](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X201) and the lighter [X201s](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X201s).

You can still find the older X200/X200s brand new, but they do not have TrackPads, which people new to ThinkPads sometimes prefer.  I have an X200s at the moment and I love it.

ThinkPad X and T series laptops are built extremely well and have excellent keyboards.  They are also well supported by Linux (see the linked site).